# can't set headers using setHeaders in /api/something/server.js

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Could anyone explain how to set headers in `api/something/+server.js` in sveltekit?

I read the docs [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#headers)

It's all about +page.server.js but not `api/folder/+server.js`

```js
export async function POST(event){
  let newheader = {"potato" : "something"}

  //how to set headers?
  return new Response({success : true})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response options object has a [`headers` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response#headers).
Also, if you want to return JSON, there is a static function [`Response.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json_static) that can be used. Otherwise you have to set the correct content type header and JSON stringify the value yourself.

E.g.

```js
return Response.json(
    { success: true },
    {
        headers: {
            'potato': 'something',
        },
    },
);
```

If you just want to indicate a successful response, you don't need any response body.
If you want to indicate an error, set `status` to something appropriate  (e.g. 400 for bad request or 500 for server error).

```js
return new Response(null, { status: 400, headers: ... });
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. This is the second time you answered one of my questions. I really appreciate the help.